# Help with mapping ActionLinks to Methods in Controllers (ASP.NET MVC2)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm on my first MVC project and still haven't got a complete hang of it.  I ran into this issue:

I have this in my View (Home/Index.aspx)

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<fieldset>
<p>
    <%: Html.TextBox("A")%> 
    <%: Html.TextBox("B") %>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Submit", "Create", "Home")%> 
</p>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

I have this in my Controller (Controllers/HomeController.cs)

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formValues)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

I haven't changed the default routes in global.asx

When I hit submit, I get the "The resource cannot be found error".  However, if I change the ActionLink to

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

and the method in the controller to:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formValues)
 {
     return View("Index");
 }
```

it works fine.

I'm a little confused because if I'm specifying the exact action method name and the controller in the ActionLink (<%: Html.ActionLink("Submit", "Create", "Home")%> ), why would it matter whether I name this method Create or Index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` which restricts it to HTTP POST requests.  Since an action link is a GET, it's not using your method.  Presumably you have **two** Index methods, one of which doesn't have that attribute and accepts GET requests.

Comment: Thanks...actually I realized that my the ActionLink doesn't work in either scenario.  It works only when I have <input type="submit" value="Save" />.

Comment: @Prabhu, well, yes, that makes sense.  That is what `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` is *supposed* to do.  Remove it and it would work.

Comment: Ok, so I have a question...on the same view, I need to have two post buttons.  Say for example, something like StackOverflow--on the same view, users can either CreateAnswer or CreateComment.  How do you handle this with MVC since there is no way to specify the method name in an <input type="submit..?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Comment: @Prabhu, the preferred way of handling this is by using two entirely separate <form> elements (BeginForm/EndForm), one for each button.  (And if SO is a proper analog, that will work perfectly, as the comment text box and the answer text box are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Prabhu, yes, that link looks like it will steer you in the right direction.